# How to "Send to PC" on EasyChair?

Tags: easychair

I'm using EasyChair for our workshop. As chair, I have our Program Committee (PC) assigned, and I've bid for each paper on behalf of each PC member. So clicking "Bidding" lists each PC member followed by the papers they should review. But, how do I send them their emails telling them what to review?

By clicking "Assignment->Send To PC" I see an email template which looks ready to go. But, there are no PC members listed on the page. If I then click "Send Email to PC members", I arrive at an error page "Error Found" - "no PC member has been selected".

Answer (score 1):

First off, note that the "Help" link on EasyChair is specific to each page. The help link on the "Assignment->Interactive Assignment" page is useful here.

Ok: under "Assignment->Interactive Assignment" the box of each reviewer must be clicked. This will increase the first number in the parentheses, and especially, make it non-zero. After that, the names will now appear at the bottom of the “Send to PC” page.